# Rails 3.2: Observers - Can I call after_something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, observers

Using Rails3.2 Observers, I found these very cool but I'm stick with a question.

Okay, we can do after_create, after_update, after_destroy,... But can I do 'after_validate'? Is there a generic for 'after_name-of-the-method-in-this-controller'?

For Example:

```
class EvaluationObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

 def after_create(record)
  Rails.logger.debug "New Evaluation = #{record}"
 end

 def after_validate(record)
  Rails.logger.debug "Validate the record = #{record}
 end

end
```

Assuming that I have a method called "validate" in my EvaluationController.rb, is that functionnal? Or I have to do another thing?

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here is the response:
https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2009/01/06/using-custom-activerecord-events-callbacks/

It was simple actually